# How to implement one vs rest classifier in a multiclass classification problem?

Tags: machine-learning, multiclass-classification, machine-learning-model, data-science-model

I have a dataset which contains 750 data points with 8 classes in the target variable. I tried implementing simple machine learning models and also did hyperparameter tuning but they results were not much impressive. The best log loss that i could get was 1.52 with a misclassification rate of 53%. What are the other methods that i could apply to improve the models performance ? Also, I want to implement `onevsrest classifier` with the hope that, it would improve the results, but implementation of the same is not clear to me although I looked in the internet for some clear codes.

```
best_alpha = np.argmin(cv_log_error_array)
clf =OneVsRestClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=alpha[int(best_alpha/2)], criterion='entropy', max_depth=max_depth[int(best_alpha%2)], random_state=42, n_jobs=-1))
clf.fit(X_traindata, y_train)
sig_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(clf, method="sigmoid")
sig_clf.fit(X_traindata, y_train)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82944/discussion-on-question-by-akash-dubey-how-to-implement-one-vs-rest-classifier-in).